# No correct signal from ATMEGA162 UART

Tags: avr, atmega, uart, rs232

I got the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzzcV9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And this code to run it:

```
#define F_CPU 4915200UL     // Quarz with 4.9152Mhz
#define BAUD 9600

#include <asf.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "helpFile.h"        // set/clear Bit (LED) 
#include <util/delay.h>

void USART_Init( unsigned int ubrr )
{
    /* Set baud rate */
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;
    /* Enable receiver ?nd transmitter */
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
    /* Set frame format 8data, 1stop bit */
    UCSR0C = (1<<URSEL0)|(1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);
}

void USART_Transmit( unsigned char data )
{
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) )
    ;
    /* Put data into bu?fer, sends the data */
    UDR0 = data;
}

void main( void )
{
    USART_Init(31);
    DDRB = ( 1 << PB0 );

    while(1)
    {
        USART_Transmit('C');
        PORTB ^= ( 1 << PB0 );  
        _delay_ms(1000);   
    }
}
```

If I connect this to an UART/USB Tool and start the Terminal Monitor with 9600Boud rate and 8n1 I get empty messages. Can you tell me what I did wrong / what to change to get it working?

Comment: The crystal in the schematic is connected incorrectly. Do you have it right on the actual board?

Comment: @venny sorry just the schematic was wrong on the board it is right (corrected it above).

Comment: You never seem to use the results of `util/setbaud.h`...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that was from older tests

Comment: Did you switch to external crystal oscillator?

Comment: The caspacitors on the crystal leads (C1 and C2) should be about 22pF, not 22uF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you stated that you use \$1\$ stop bit, \$\texttt{USBS0}\$ enables two. But that should not interfere with anything.

Bigger problem is in baud rate generator. Baud rate in normal mode is calculated as \$\dfrac{f_{osc}}{16\cdot (\texttt{UBRR+1})}\$. So UBRR is \$\dfrac{f_{osc}}{16\cdot BR}-1\$ and for \$4.915200\, \mathrm{MHz}\$ it is \$31\$, not \$51\$.

Edit: Another problem found, incorrect bit shifting in UART configuration register C. It should be \$\texttt{3<<UCSZ00}\$, not \$\texttt{3<<UCSZ01}\$.

Comment: I changed it from 51 to 31 and that the terminal to 8n2 but the result is the same (I receive something but not the character)

Comment: @kimliv Answer updated, does it work now?

Comment: okay that two pieces have been wrong i will correct it also in the code above so others can use it.